# To add start index to a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
a = [1 2 3]
```

I want to add 0 as first index to the list. How can I do that?

output :

```
a = [0 1 2 3]
```

Comment: `print help(list.insert)`

Comment: Do you have a numpy array, or a list? They're quite different types.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: `help` does the printing and returns `None`. You don't need to `print` the `None`.

Comment: @user2357112 He he.. Never actually tried `help` in a real program, I always thought `help` simply returns the string and interactive shell echoes its return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`list.insert`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.insert(0, 0)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Using slice assignment:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[:0] = [0]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

**UPDATE** according to tag change.

Use [`numpy.insert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.insert(a, 0, 0)
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

or [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> np.hstack([[0], a])
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list.insert (reference: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

**list.insert(i, x)**
Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

```
a.insert(0,0)
```